# What kind of keypoints are detected by MPSImageFindKeypoints?

Tags: ios, computer-vision, arkit, metal

Apple documentation mentions a Metal kernel called MPSImageFindKeypoints but there is no information about what kind of features is that. From the parameters, it looks similar to FAST keypoints. By which algorithm is this kernel powered?

Are those features the ones that ARKit uses? (Accessible via rawFeaturePoints)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, those keypoints are just to threshold the image, albeit really quickly using Metal (much faster than if you looped through each pixel in the image region). They are not meant to be any particular type of keypoint.

Though, you could probably (creatively) use it and a couple of other Metal calls to calculate FAST features really quickly.

Comment: Incidentally. May I ask why you are looking for FAST features in the ARKit environment?

Comment: I'm not looking for FAST features in particular. I was looking for any kind features that would be usable out-of-the-box and Metal-accelerated. I was just wondering whether those are the features, part of Apple's internal acv3d library.

Comment: Right, are you trying to modify those filters then? Because you do have access to rawFeaturesPoints. What more are you looking for from your features?

Comment: I'm also looking for GPU-accelerated features. I noticed that the `rawFeaturePoints` don't contain any descriptors, and they are somewhat limited in terms of their perceived depth from the camera. Also you can only run them in the context of an ARKit session. I would like to run feature detection offline

Answer (score 0):

The MPSImageKeyPoints filter is an optimised gaussian subtract feature extraction algorithm that works best with blobs. I'm sure you know that blobs have gaussian distribution features, hence the term gaussian subtract as the base process, which can be optimised as a gaussian pyramid, and further as a LaPlacian pyramid subtract. the process is as follows:

1-change the curves/contrast of your original image
2-set a stack of gaussian blurs with n sigma distances for your kernel on the original image
3-subtract each blurred image from the original image
4-Get a threshold max across the stack of images including x and y and the index of the image in the stack representing the radius coordinates
5-draw over that location (say in black for stars) across the stack
6-Repeat the process until you're out of values above the threshold

So it's best suited for post filtering processes for finding important features for particular applications. Some that come to mind are star extraction on a stack of astronomical exposure images to avoid the "star trail" effect, or creating a frame by frame mocap type joint localisation with balls attached to the actor's body, or perhaps even extracting elliptical blobs that may occur in a natural/synthetic setting.